# Using case statement inside ORDER BY - "Incorrect syntax near ','"

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *

FROM ##RawTrans

ORDER BY GroupBy ASC, 
    CASE WHEN @RepType = 'Emp' THEN 
        CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0 THEN [Code] ELSE [Name] END, [Date], [Time]
    CASE WHEN @RepType = 'ClockEmp' THEN
        [Clock], CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0 THEN [Code] ELSE [Name] END, [Date], [Time]
    CASE WHEN @RepType = 'EmpClock' THEN
        CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0 THEN [Code] ELSE [Name] END, [Clock], [Date], [Time]     
END
```

Can someone please help me to know where's my error in this code ?

I am getting an error in line 7

> [Incorrect syntax near ',']

GroupBy is a variable that was declared before this code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `case` expression has to return a single value, you can't have it return comma separated field names.

You have to make a `case` for each value, something like:

```
ORDER BY
  GroupBy ASC,
  CASE WHEN @RepType = 'ClockEmp' THEN [Clock] ELSE '' end,
  CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0 THEN [Code] ELSE [Name] END,
  CASE WHEN @RepType = 'EmpClock' THEN [Clock] ELSE '' end,
  [Date],
  [Time]
```

Comment: +1 I posted a virtually identical answer, 3 seconds after yours! We don't know whether `[Clock]` is a character, so it might be better to remove the `ELSE ''`, so that those cases evaluate to NULL otherwise.

Comment: What a beautiful answer Thank You.. It just worked fine.. 
And @Guffa you're totally right about the '' ... Thank You..

Answer (score 2):

You have a `CASE` inside of a `CASE` but don't end both of them:

```
CASE WHEN @RepType = 'Emp' THEN 
        CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 0 THEN [Code] ELSE [Name] END,
```

You end your second case, but not your first one.

If your intention is to organize by different criteria, you're going to need to reorganize your CASE statements so that they affect one column order choice at a time.

Comment: So that means we can't use multiple columns in the same case statement.. I appreciate your answer Thank you